# Change Multiple Google Map Markers Position On Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Here is how my website currently looks : https://gyazo.com/ee7851e912a1b7fb4118f80ad0f35a53

It shows the delivery drivers on the left and the delivery route for the first driver.  I want to be able to click any of the other drivers and show their delivery route. Here is the HTML I currently have for each driver:

```
<li onclick="changeDelivery(54.35024,-6.26928,54.38252,-6.30836);">
            <!-- driver info -->
        </li>
```

And here is my javascript:

```
function initMap() {
var pickup = {lat: 54.34633, lng: -6.27175};
var dropoff = {lat: 54.34786, lng: -6.25146};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: pickup,
    scrollwheel: true,
    zoom: 7,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
});

var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    map: map,
    suppressMarkers: true,
    polylineOptions: {
        strokeColor: "#24A4EA",
        strokeWeight: 5
    }
});

// Set destination, origin and travel mode.
var request = {
    destination: dropoff,
    origin: pickup,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
};

// Pass the directions request to the directions service.
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            // Display the route on the map.
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        }
});

var pickupIcon = new google.maps.MarkerImage('img/pickup-icon.png');
var dropoffIcon = new google.maps.MarkerImage('img/dropoff-icon.png');

var pickupMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: pickup,
    map: map,
    icon: pickupIcon
});

var dropoffMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: dropoff,
    map: map,
    icon: dropoffIcon
});
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);

function changeDelivery(pickupLat,pickupLng,dropoffLat,dropoffLng) {
    var pickup = {lat: pickupLat, lng: pickupLng};
    var dropoff = {lat: dropoffLat, lng: dropoffLng};
}
```

At the moment I am trying to get call the function changeDelivery by clicking on the list item and expecting the parameters of it to update the pickup and dropoff markers on the map to the new coordinates.  Any reason this isn't working or how should I go about doing this?

Thanks,
Jamie

Answer (score 1):

Your `changeDelivery()` isn't manipulating the map at all yet.  You need to remove the current markers with `pickupMarker.setMap(null)`, and `dropoffMarker.setMap(null)`, then put the new locations into the markers with `pickupMarker.setMap(pickup)`, and `dropoffMarker.setMap(dropoff)`

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#add